# Can we no longer vote to migrate to meta?

Tags: support, migration, close-reasons, vote-to-close

I wanted to vote to migrate [this question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/36159/10559) to Meta, since it's asking about reputation. But that close reason seems to have disappeared.

When (and why) did this change happen? "Migrate to Meta" isn't as useful as the full suite of migration paths that full sites get, but it still has its uses.

EDIT: Never mind, the option still exists, it's just in a different place now. My bad.

Comment: Not your bad at all, the new dialogs have a lot of problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's still there, but maybe you can't find it because of [recent changes to the close UI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346638/295232)? If you click the 'flag' link, it's under 'needs improvement' (this step is skipped if you click 'close'), then 'A community specific reason' and then 'This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network'. The only reason this last option wouldn't be shown is if the question is more than 60 days old; only younger questions can be migrated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Huh, interesting! So it's still an option if you flag, but not if you VTC?

Comment: Not sure, since I don't have the reputation to vote to close. On sites where I do, Meta is still visible as a migration target. Perhaps you could share your version of my 3rd screenshot?

Comment: It's there for closing too, just skip the first dialog shown above.